# Globally poll which files are being dragged in Windows API?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, com, drag-and-drop

I'm wondering if it's possible to globally poll which (if any) files are currently being dragged in Windows using the Windows API, independently of any particular window.

For example, I'm doing some stuff with networking where, when the user drags a file to the edge of the screen, it notifies a separate computer that the file has hit the screen edge. I've got my program running in the background, but it's not windowed, and it's hard (impossible) to place my window around all 4 screen edges.

I'm doing this in Python, but if I have to use another language and write a wrapper around it that's fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [hook `DoDragDrop`](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=480710).